# How can I call stop a while loop while it is running and not finished yet?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

Triggering Ctrl+C with a text from Discord itself?

How can I use close() with a text from Discord to stop the while loop even if it is not finished yet?

How can I stop client.run(TOKEN) with a  text from Discord?

Comment: You should include the code that you are trying to stop.

Comment: if message.content == 'start':
        while True:
            my_function('ABC', 10)
            time.sleep(3)    # This will run continously and I want to know how to stop with a 
                                     # message.content == 's'

if message.content == 's':
        await client_discord.close()

Comment: That isn't enough context.  You should copy and paste a minimal working example of what your code does, or the code itself into your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SIGINT signal, which is the signal when you Control-C. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) for more information. You can then get the bot to send the signal to itself:

```py
import os
import signal

def do_control_c_interrupt():
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

Then, you can `do_control_c_interrupt()` inside of a command if you need to stop the bot.

Comment: I want to stop the function which contains a while loop because it will restart every 3 seconds and continue to run. I don't want to stop it at a specific time but want to stop running the function when the Discord text is sent.

Comment: Sending `SIGINT` will terminate the entire program (and perform cleanup if you made a signal handler), so the loop will die. You can add `do_control_c_interrupt` inside of the command for whatever you want the command to be. Also why are you running the bot every 3 seconds?